# AngularJS 1.5, сборка проекта

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

Пытаюсь собрать свой проект, ни как не получается. Все работает идеально, а сборка не проходит, валится с вот такими ошибками:

```
ERROR in ./_bower_components/angularjs-slider/dist/rzslider.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'angular' in C:\Users\АСУ\Desktop
\appSoc\socialist\app\_bower_components\angularjs-slider\dist
 @ ./_bower_components/angularjs-slider/dist/rzslider.js 12:4-32

ERROR in ./_bower_components/angular-clipboard/angular-clipboard.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'angular' in C:\Users\АСУ\Desktop
\appSoc\socialist\app\_bower_components\angular-clipboard
 @ ./_bower_components/angular-clipboard/angular-clipboard.js 4:8-36
```

Конфиг webpack'a:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        all: [
            "./_bower_components/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
            // 70 файлов
            "./core/auth-manager/auth-manager.service.js"
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname+"/dist",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    }
}
```

Comment: Но зачем использовать webpack с первым ангуляром?

Comment: @Qwertiy, с радостью бы узнал альтернативы. Я уже понял, что webpack для меня не лучший выбор, но увы, за неимением опыта сборки JS-проектов, понятия не имею, что мне выбрать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по ошибке, у вас не стоит angular

```
bower install angular -S
```